# Is this milky quartz a stone age tool?

Tags: archaeology, research

[image][image][image][image]I found this piece of quartz at Benbo Mt Co. Sligo Ireland.There are many Megaliths in this area in the Dartry Mt range.Its 3 inches in length and appears to have been fashioned as a tool.I found it about a third of the way up Benbo Mountain.The pointed end appears to have been used to chip maybe other rocks.

Comment: @Dave: In my opinion your question is off-topic for this site. If you were asking about the rock type, that is about earth science & would be on-topic, but you already know the rock type. Questions about the possibility of anthropomorphic use of the stone (possibility of it being a stone tool use by humans or pre-humans) that would be archeology or history.

Comment: Hi Fred, I taged it archaeology, I don't know how to go further with my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Fred and Dave Don't be suprised if any picture of a rock posted on other SE sites gets migrated over here to Earth Science SE.

Comment: Hi Dave, although I doubt that the particular quartz fragment is a tool there is the possibility that it could be a tool.  It appears some research on quartz tools has been done with a particular emphasis in Ireland.  See the following paper: https://www.lithicsireland.ie/phd_quartz_lithic_technology_chap_3.html

Comment: Thank you Friddy for that paper link, much appreciated

Comment: It is a tool. Look at the edges. It is not flint, for that i say it was a .... but well in my opinion it should be posted at history exchange. When I diged once we were two geologists and twelve historicians and we had absolutely no idea about what were we taking from soil and always ask them, but as you wish. You are here a lot before me, no relation with the site neither. just this morning was specialy...we received 7 or 8 I think and I became a bit crazy again because my massachusetts answer has some extra importance on my tricky life. any positive again btw, but well, what matters is...

Comment: @Universal_learner History SE will migrate this here, every time.

Comment: @Spencer. Ok, but in my opinion they shouldn't. Maybe because Iberian Peninsule has interest on paleoantropology, but least at Spain practicaly any geologist know anything about this and historicians does. At Lexetxiki where I excavated, the history students told me a lot of things, but of course when I took any stone (it was oxidative environment with hemetite nodules, so frequently) I always asked them.

Comment: @Universal_learner That's probably a good discussion for Meta History SE.

Comment: @Spencer I agree, but it is not me who is gonna start another discussion. I tried some other communities. I was interested in neuroscience but my questions weren't accurated. They read it I guess, and I also think they should accept them when is paleoantropology related.

Comment: @Spencer My question was if modern neurology endorsed Freud. They said it was a duplicate of another question that was different. One tried to reopen it at a chatroom but they didn't. I am a bit tired and the feedback I left stack is clear. I want to stay at the site not creating more troubles.The coding policy is perfect to optimize but in culture my opinion is they should adaptate it. I am a bit tired of saying it but well give them time. It is in beta mode and the team is wonderful.

Comment: @Universal_Learner For the Freud thing, [HSM SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) ( which needs some love) might have worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about archaeology, not earth science.